# Why Angular 2 use Observables instead of simple arrays in routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

[ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html) fields are Observables. For instance we want to get an id parameter or just nth segment of URL. Instead of simple maps or arrays we uses Observables. Is this over-usage of asynchrony or really needed for a purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the **current** version of a parameter using the [`snapshot` field of the ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#snapshot-anchor).

But by default, the router reuses the same component if you navigate from a route to the same route, only changing parameters. So you need an Observable to be able to react to the changes of the parameter values from inside that component.

Let's say for example that you have a list of exercises to display. When you click an exercise, you go to `/exercises/1`. Inside the template of the component displaying the exercise, you have a "Next" link to `/exercises/2`. Clicking on that link will make the `params` Observable emit a new value. But the router won't create a new instance of ActivatedRoute, and won't create a new instance of ExerciseComponent. The ExerciseComponent needs to subscribe to the params observable in order to load the details of the exercise 2 when the event is emitted.

If you don't have such a link, then the snapshot is all you need, and it does contain the parameters as a regular object.